# Two firewalls with two login_form and two different AuthenticationSuccessHandlers but only one used for both

Tags: php, symfony

Pretty much all is in the title.

I come here before to be sure that is a bug before report it as an issue on symfony/symfony.

I have the following security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    chalasr: { password: chalasr, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }

    firewalls:
        admin:
            pattern:            ^/admin
            form_login:
                provider:       in_memory
                login_path:     /admin/login
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
                success_handler: admin.authentication_success_handler
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
            anonymous:          true

        login_api:
            pattern:  ^/v1/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                provider: in_memory
                check_path: /v1/login_check
                require_previous_session: false
                username_parameter: username
                password_parameter: password
                success_handler: api.authentication_success_handler

        api:
            pattern:   ^/v1/
            stateless: true
            lexik_jwt: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/v1/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/v1/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

As you can see, I have two login firewalls, one for routes matching with `^/admin` and one for those matching with `^/v1`.
The two `form_login` have **one respective** `authentication_success_handler` set.

The api handler:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

 class ApiAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
        die('interecepted by api');
    }
}
```

The admin handler:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class AdminAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        die('interecepted by admin');
    }
}
```

Services:

```
admin.authentication_success_handler:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\AdminAuthenticationSuccessHandler
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.on_authentication_success, method: onAuthenticationSuccess }

api.authentication_success_handler:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ApiAuthenticationSuccessHandler
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.on_authentication_success, method: onAuthenticationSuccess }
```

The problem is that the `admin.authentication_success_handler` is the one used for both firewalls, it says "intercepted by admin" at all, for the api login route, and for the admin login route (form).

My first goal is too make stuffs that totally depend on the firewall used, and this behavior causes a bug in my application, because of the separation admin/api.
At start when I discovered the bug, I used LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle and FOSUserBundle for the api, and SonataAdminBundle (with FOSUB) for the admin, on Symfony 2.8.
Then I upgraded to 3.0 plus removed any 3rd party security bundles, in order to avoid any doubt about these and so to be sure about that is coming from symfony. (this is why I use a simple plaintext encoder, as simple as possible).

Am I right when I assume it's a bug?
Or I just do something wrong?

Because the thing is apparently not documented yet and we can find lots of different (working or not) implementations.

**EDIT**

Hi @tftd, thank's for your work.

I'm really sorry but I just too shortened my code to make the question readable, so the missing `anonymous: true` in the two is a simple typo from my side, I added them.

In fact, the implementation works fine in a project that is finished, it is separated in an api and an admin, both on different hosts, the admin firewall with a login form provided by FOSUserBundle and the api firewall with a simple /login_check endpoint that provides a JWT, then users send authenticated requests to `/v1/*` routes with the token as header (bearer).

I upgraded to 3.0 to be in phase, and I used a simple `in_memory` to avoid any doubt about 3rd party bundles (FOSUserBundle success handling, LexikJWT success handling or anything else that can be the cause of the error), and I hope I really avoid any doubt about them.

You can see my simple routing.yml (keep in mind that I'm presenting the issue with a sample that is just used to see how the login success behave, it's absolutely not a real-world usage, but I come from the same behavior on a real-world usage).

```
// app/config/routing.yml
fos_user:
    prefix: /admin
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

api_login_check:
    path: /v1/login_check
```

The routes `/admin/*` are managed by  FOSUserBundle which provide the login form, my goal is just to see if the two login success are intercepted, and in fact, they are.

The problem was coming from that my two listeners was listening on `security.interactive_login`, it looked like this:

```
class ApiAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {

        return $this->onAuthenticationSuccess($event->getRequest(), $event->getAuthenticationToken());
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        die('Interecepted by api');
    }
}
```

And the two services declarations looked like:

```
api.authentication_success_handler:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerApi ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

With the tags set, only one listener is fired.
By removing the tags, respective handlers are properly called on each firewall.

Conclusion, no need of tag an AuthenticationSuccessListener (except for any other reason than throw the onAuthenticationSuccess), and if you tag it, tag it as a `security.on_authentication_success` event, not on `security.interactive_login`, because, no matter of the handler defined in security.yml, the first will be used onInteractiveLogin and so the second will be totally ignored.

Thank's @Federico for the good answer, and thanks again @tdtd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem lie when you subscribe `AdminAuthenticationSuccessHandler`'s `onAuthenticationSuccess` method to the event `security.on_authentication_success`. It will be trigger every time a user is authenticated by one provider, it does not matter which. Since you have register `admin.authentication_success_handler` first, it will be run first.

I'm not quite sure of that, because the event name is [`security.authentication.success`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/AuthenticationEvents.php#L25), but try to change your service definition with

```
admin.authentication_success_handler:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\AdminAuthenticationSuccessHandler

api.authentication_success_handler:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ApiAuthenticationSuccessHandler
```

Comment: The problem was because I used the `security.on_interactive_login` to call onAuthenticationSuccess manually (see my edit). If I replace by `security.on_authentication_success` as in my question, all works well. If I remove the tags, all works well too, so I give you the point! t Thank's

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why your configuration doesn't displaying "loop" errors. According to the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html#be-sure-the-login-page-isn-t-secure-redirect-loop) your `login` path should be accessible by anonymous users and `login_check` should be under your firewall. In the current situation you have the `login` path under `/admin/` which requires `ROLE_USER`.

Your configuration should rather look something like this:

security:

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user: { password: password, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    admin_login:
        anonymous: ~
        pattern: ^/admin/login$

    admin:
        pattern:        ^/admin
        provider:       in_memory
        form_login:
            login_path:             /admin/login
            check_path:             /admin/login_check
            default_target_path:    /admin/
            success_handler:        admin.authentication_success_handler
        logout:
            path:       /admin/logout
            target:     /admin/login

    api:
        pattern:             ^/v1
        stateless:           true
        form_login:
            provider:        in_memory
            check_path:      /v1/login_check
            success_handler: api.authentication_success_handler
            require_previous_session: false


access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/v1/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/v1, role: ROLE_USER }
```

In your `routing.yml` make sure you have as well as change the links in your templates:

```
admin_logout:
    path: /admin/logout

admin_login_check:
    path: /admin/login_check

api_login_check:
    path: /v1/login_check
```

The `SecurityController`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class SecurityController  extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login",       name="api_login")
     * @Route("/admin/login", name="admin_login")
     * @Template("::login.html.twig")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
            'login_path'    => $request->get('_route') == 'admin_login' ? '/admin/login_check' : '/v1/login_check'
        );
    }
}

?>
```

The `app/Resources/views/login.html.twig` template:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ login_path }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Service and success handler definitions are absolutely identical to what you've posted.

The code above is rather a proof of concept to show you that the different firewalls work just fine with different `success_handler`'s. This is so, because in each firewall you have defined the `success_handler` you want to be called when a successful authentication has been made. Furthermore, in real life, you won't be needing `/v1/login`, because the `POST` request to your `API` should contain a header with the authentication/api key.

As for your API implementation - I have a feeling you're approach might be wrong. Some time ago I was using [ApiKeyAuthenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html) implementation to create REST APIs. It's a good "base ground" to understand how to start API your implementation. However, with newer versions of Symfony (3.0+), you could use [Guard Authentication](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/guard-authentication.html), which appears to be a bit easier.

Comment: Hi @tftd,  I edited my queston, the problem was coming from my side.

Comment: Now I see. Well glad I could help anyway! :)